# Ошибка при авторизации Docker на Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

```
$ docker login
Log in with your Docker ID or email address to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com/ to create one.
You can log in with your password or a Personal Access Token (PAT). Using a limited-scope PAT grants better security and is required for organizations using SSO. Learn more at https://docs.docker.com/go/access-tokens/

Username: email
Password: 
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: `$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock; id` ?

Comment: srw-rw-rw- 1 root docker  /var/run/docker.sock
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(kvm),122(lpadmin),133(lxd),134(sambashare)

Comment: либо добавьте пользователя в группу `docker`, либо используйте программу `sudo`: `$ sudo docker ...`

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Помогло!